# Corrupted Mathematica file

Tags: front-end, notebooks

It has occurred several times that Mathematica notebooks seem to get corrupted probably by cloud services (happened with dropbox, NutShare). Sometimes, an entire cell or chapter/section become `NULL`, and sometimes, they look like the following (all codes are present but scrambled into some output-like text)

**I wonder how to fix them and how to avoid?**

[image]

Comment: [Don't use the bugs tag](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/192/72682). I cannot think how we can help without a sample corrupted notebook file. There's probably nothing in that screenshot that will indicate why it's happening. You could create an MD5 signature of the notebook before and after transfer to check integrity. Either the upload is bad - or it's some kind of encoding issue. If we had both before+after notebooks they could be compared with a diff tool to see which bytes change.

Comment: Is your screenshot the text file that you think is corrupted? That is not a Mathematica file format, that's a text file of Mathematica input/output from a kernel.

Comment: @flinty Unfortunately the original file before the upload is gone, even from the version history. And such an issue doesn't happen that often for me to reproduce such corruption. In any case, how do I share a sample file on this site in case I do reproduce the corruption?

Comment: @ktm Yes, it does look like an output file. But it's indeed the `.nb` Notebook file I used to do the computation, and I have never told Mathematica to make an output (since I don't need one).